# Format y axis as percent

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have an existing plot that was created with pandas like this:

```
df['myvar'].plot(kind='bar')
```

The y axis is format as float and I want to change the y axis to percentages.  All of the solutions I found use ax.xyz syntax and **I can only place code below the line above that creates the plot** (I cannot add ax=ax to the line above.)

**How can I format the y axis as percentages without changing the line above?**

Here is the solution I found **but requires that I redefine the plot**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

data = [8,12,15,17,18,18.5]
perc = np.linspace(0,100,len(data))

fig = plt.figure(1, (7,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.plot(perc, data)

fmt = '%.0f%%' # Format you want the ticks, e.g. '40%'
xticks = mtick.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xticks)

plt.show()
```

Link to the above solution: [Pyplot: using percentage on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294360/pyplot-using-percentage-on-x-axis)

Comment: Could you please change your accepted answer to the approach implemented natively in matplotlib? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319915/1840471

Answer (score 356, accepted):

This is a few months late, but I have created [PR#6251](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/6251) with matplotlib to add a new `PercentFormatter` class. With this class you just need one line to reformat your axis (two if you count the import of `matplotlib.ticker`):

```
import ...
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

ax = df['myvar'].plot(kind='bar')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
```

`PercentFormatter()` accepts three arguments, `xmax`, `decimals`, `symbol`. `xmax` allows you to set the value that corresponds to 100% on the axis. This is nice if you have data from 0.0 to 1.0 and you want to display it from 0% to 100%. Just do `PercentFormatter(1.0)`.

The other two parameters allow you to set the number of digits after the decimal point and the symbol. They default to `None` and `'%'`, respectively. `decimals=None` will automatically set the number of decimal points based on how much of the axes you are showing.

**Update**

[`PercentFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter) was introduced into  Matplotlib proper in version 2.1.0.

Comment: This works fantastically. But PercentFormatter(1.0) seems to format as 10.0% 20.0% rather than 10% 20% (maybe a typo in your answer?)

Comment: @DrXorile. Most likely updates to matplotlib. The official docs supersede anything in here. I can compare when I have a chance

Comment: Oh, i think it's because the default is decimal=None, which auto-generates the number of decimals depending on the range. So if the range is less than 50%, it does 10.0%. More than 50% it does 10%. So apologies - your answer is correct, depending on other parameters.

Comment: how would you apply to secondary y axis?

Comment: @JeJe. You can set a formatter on whatever axis you want

Comment: Nive answer! In my case, I used `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())` to avoid saving a `ax` plot first.

Comment: **Very strange**: For me, this simply added '%', but without multiplying by 100.
OTOH, the answer by erwanp worked as expected.
I didn't explore the issue further.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio. Which version didn't multiply by 100? `PercentFormatter(1.0)`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I was using it with no arguments, as you posted. Using `PercentFormatter(1.0)` did the job.
It seems the default is `PercentFormatter(100)`, which is most unexpected.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio. That's covered in the answer. Why would anything besides "no transformation" be an unexpected default?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Because 1.0=100%, they are the same *number*!
It's as if changing to scientific notation using `x1e6` changed `1000000` into `1000000x1e6`... it changes the numbers.
I would have never thought otherwise, and that is certainly the reason why the answer by erwanp works as expected without needing any further input parameters, as in `PercentFormatter`. It's possibly nice to have the further flexibility of `xmax`, but the default is clearly wrong, it is not "no transformation".
I must be missing something...

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio that's fairly convincing. At the time I wrote it, my thought was that the input units would already be %. Unfortunately, this is now part of the matplotlib API. If you want, you could submit an issue, and possibly a PR to fix it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I will try finding some time to do that. In the meantime, I suggest you add a clarification in the answer and/or upvote my comments, so other readers are aware.
It's strange that Dr Xorile didn't point this out, having experimented with `xmax`.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio. The paragraph below the code snippet is explicit

Comment: Hi, thanks for the nice answer! I used `PercentFormatter(xmax = 1.0, decimals = 0, symbol = r'\%', is_latex = True)` and it worked! I do have one question however.

I always use `matplotlib.rc('text', usetex = True)` such that the axis tick labels are displayed in a "good-looking" Roman font. But the percentage tick labels seem to be ignoring it and always get displayed in the original font. How can I make it be displayed in Roman font? Thanks!

Comment: @zyy. It's been a while, but you could try turning off `is_latex` and removing the `\ `

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hi, thanks for the reply, however that did not work...

Answer (score 167):

pandas dataframe plot will return the `ax` for you, And then you can start to manipulate the axes whatever you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,5))

# you get ax from here
ax = df.plot()
type(ax)  # matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot

# manipulate
vals = ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,.2%}'.format(x) for x in vals])
```

[image]

Comment: This will have undesired effects as soon as you pan/zoom the graph interactively

Comment: Million times easier than trying to use `matplotlib.ticker` function formatters!

Comment: How do you then limit the y axis to say (0,100%)?
I tried ax.set_ylim(0,100) but that doesn't seem to work!!

Comment: @mpour only the labels of the yticks are changed, so the limits are still in natural units. Setting ax.set_ylim(0, 1) will do the trick.

Comment: Not sure why but this answer mislabelled the ticks whereas erwanp's correctly labeled axross the entire axis.

Answer (score 97):

[Jianxun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014134/jianxun-li)'s solution did the job for me but broke the y value indicator at the bottom left of the window.

I ended up using `FuncFormatter`instead (and also stripped the uneccessary trailing zeroes as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997799/most-pythonic-way-to-print-at-most-some-number-of-decimal-places)):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,5))

ax = df.plot()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0%}'.format(y)))
```

Generally speaking I'd recommend using `FuncFormatter` for label formatting: it's reliable, and versatile.

[image]

Comment: You can simplify the code even more: `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter('{0:.0%}'.format))`. AKA no need for the lambda, let format do the work.

Comment: @DanielHimmelstein can you explain this a little bit?  Particularly inside the { }.  Not sure how my 0.06 gets turned into 6% using that with the python format.  Also great solution.  Seems to work much more reliably than using .set_ticklabels

Comment: @DChaps `'{0:.0%}'.format` creates a [formatting function](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-examples). The `0` before the colon tells the formatter to replace the curly-brackets and its contents with the first argument passed to the function. The part after the colon, `.0%`, tells the formatter how to render the value. The `.0` specifies 0 decimal places and `%` specifies rendering as a percent.

Answer (score 60):

For those who are looking for the quick one-liner:

```
plt.gca().set_yticklabels([f'{x:.0%}' for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()])
```

or, if you've saved your `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object into variable `ax`:

```
ax.set_yticklabels([f'{x:.0f}%' for x in ax.get_yticks()])
```

this assumes

- import: `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`
- Python >=3.6 for f-String formatting. For older versions, replace `f'{x:.0%}'` with `'{:.0%}'.format(x)`

Comment: For me, Daniel Himmelstein's answer worked whereas this answer changed the scale

Comment: If setting tick labels changes the scale, you should issue the scale selection command after this.

Answer (score 20):

I'm late to the game but I just realize this: `ax` can be replaced with `plt.gca()` for those who are not using axes and just subplots.

Echoing @Mad Physicist answer, using the package `PercentFormatter` it would be:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(1))
#if you already have ticks in the 0 to 1 range. Otherwise see their answer
```

Answer (score 6):

I propose an alternative method using `seaborn`

**Working code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data=np.random.rand(10,2)*100
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
ax= sns.lineplot(data=df, markers= True)
ax.set(xlabel='xlabel', ylabel='ylabel', title='title')
#changing ylables ticks
y_value=['{:,.2f}'.format(x) + '%' for x in ax.get_yticks()]
ax.set_yticklabels(y_value)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in one line without importing anything:
`plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter('{}%'.format))`

If you want integer percentages, you can do:
`plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter('{:.0f}%'.format))`

You can use either `ax.yaxis` or `plt.gca().yaxis`. `FuncFormatter` is still part of `matplotlib.ticker`, but you can also do `plt.FuncFormatter` as a shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer of @[erwanp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5622825/erwanp), you can use the  [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) of Python 3,

```py
x = '2'
percentage = f'{x}%' # 2%
```

inside the [`FuncFormatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) and combined with a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions) expression.

All wrapped:

```py
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: f'{y}%'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another one line solution if the yticks are between 0 and 1:

```
plt.yticks(plt.yticks()[0], ['{:,.0%}'.format(x) for x in plt.yticks()[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

add a line of code

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter())