# How can I concatenate symbol ("%") to integer value in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, charts, string-concatenation, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I am facing an issue here. I have a `Dataframe` column whose values I need to put as `value+%` i.e. say `10%, 15%` etc.

However, I am able to put the values as string type in the excel sheet after writing but while I plot the graph, the value is being considered as a string and hence the chart is not getting generated.

I need to paste the value with the `%` symbol in the concerned column as well as I need to plot the graph while writing to the excel sheet.

Any solution  for this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: related and probable dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357611/format-y-axis-as-percent

Answer (score 0):

For writing the value in excel you can use

```
str(value) + '%'
```

While plotting graph access the values by slicing the last character(%) and convert it to number by using [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function.

```
eval(value[:-1])
```