# Show values for Stacked bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, bar-chart

I would like to show the % values inside the stacked bar.

```
I have this dataframe: `df=pd.DataFrame(data=([[ 0.13214286,  0.13928571,  0.16      ,  0.13285714,  0.14571429, 0.14714286,  0.14285714], [ 0.11833333,  0.12666667,  0.14833333,  0.13833333,  0.145, 0.17166667,  0.15166667],[ 0.15666667,  0.15666667,  0.14333333,  0.11333333,  0.17, 0.12666667,  0.13333333],[ 0.13333333,  0.16166667,  0.16      ,  0.145     ,  0.14833333,
     0.12333333,  0.12833333], [ 0.1075    ,  0.135     ,  0.105     ,  0.1425    ,  0.1875  ,0.1525    ,  0.17 ],[ 0.13833333,  0.13888889,  0.12944444,  0.14722222,  0.16166667, 0.14611111,  0.13833333],
   [ 0.14714286,  0.145     ,  0.12571429,  0.13      ,  0.15285714,
     0.13714286,  0.16214286],[ 0.147     ,  0.147     ,  0.14      ,  0.154     ,  0.132 , 0.139     ,  0.141     ],[ 0.1445    ,  0.1325    ,  0.146     ,  0.129     ,  0.147 , 0.143     ,  0.158     ],[ 0.145     ,  0.14083333,  0.14583333,  0.13666667,  0.14666667, 0.13916667,  0.14583333],
   [ 0.12375   ,  0.1325    ,  0.14625   ,  0.14375   ,  0.1525    ,
     0.16125   ,  0.14      ], [ 0.142     ,  0.1545    ,  0.137     ,  0.1425    ,  0.169     ,  0.1265    ,  0.1285    ], [ 0.13730769,  0.14      ,  0.15307692,  0.13961538,  0.13846154,  0.15076923,  0.14076923]]),columns=[u'1.Fully agree', u'2.Agree', u'3.Neither agree nor disagree', u'4.Disagree', u'5.Strongly disagree',  u'6.Impossible to answer: not applicable to my work',
   u'7.I prefer not to answer'],index=[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E', u'F', u'G', u'H', u'I', u'J', u'K', u'L', u'M'])`
```

and I am plotting the data:

```
    likert_colors = ['green','lightgreen','lightyellow','orange','red','lightgrey', 'grey']
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True, edgecolor='none',color=likert_colors)

horiz_offset = 1.03
vert_offset = 1.
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_facecolor("white")
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(horiz_offset, vert_offset))
```

getting this chart:
[image: Likert_chart]

Comment: This post seems relvant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357611/format-y-axis-as-percent.

Comment: These are two questions. Each of them already has an answer somewhere. If you have a problem, divide it into small parts and search for a solution for each part separately. If you then have a problem implementing a solution, ask specifically about that problem.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I cant figure out how to show values in a stacked bar plot.

Comment: That could well be. But [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397549/stack-bar-plot-in-matplotlib-and-add-label-to-each-section-and-suggestions) shows one way to do it, so you would want to try implementing one of the solutions from its answer and clearly state at which point you have the problem. You can do so by [edit]ing this question or asking a new one.