# Getting values and probabilities into a Matplotlib cumulative distribution function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a plot that shows Cumulative Distribution values and a 'survival function' as well.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values, base = np.histogram(serWEB, bins=100)
cumulative = np.cumsum(values)
# plot the cumulative function
plt.plot(base[:-1], cumulative, c='blue')
plt.title('Cumulative Distribution')
plt.xlabel('X Data')
plt.ylabel('Y Data')
# survival function next  
plt.plot(base[:-1], len(serWEB)-cumulative, c='green')
plt.show()
```

This plot shows the values as the main Y-Axis.
I am interested in adding a 2nd Y-Axis on the right to show the percentages.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) and [`matplotlib.ticker.Formatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=percentformatter#matplotlib.ticker.Formatter) should do what you need. First get the current axis, then create a "twin" of it using `twinx()`:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
...
ax = plt.gca()  # returns the current axes
ax = ax.twinx() # create twin xaxis
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(1.0))
```

There are quite a few ways you can format the percentage:

> [`PercentFormatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=percentformatter#matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter) accepts three arguments, max, decimals, symbol. max allows you to set the value that corresponds to 100% on the axis.
>   This is nice if you have data from 0.0 to 1.0 and you want to display
>   it from 0% to 100%. Just do PercentFormatter(1.0).
>
> The other two parameters allow you to set the number of digits after the decimal point and the symbol. They default to None and '%',
>   respectively. decimals=None will automatically set the number of
>   decimal points based on how much of the axes you are showing.<sup>[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319915/499581)]</sup>

Comment: What I want to accomplish is to have the values on Y-Axis #1 and then the relative percentages on Y-Axis #2.  The solution above just converted a raw value of e.g. 150 to "15000 %" on Y-Axis 2.  I am looking for the ratio of 150/total #  (a percent) to be Y-Axis 2.

Comment: @MarkGinsburg: I'm not sure what your total is, so I can't really compare anything. Basically all you really should need to do is adjust the number in `PercentFormatter()`,  for example you could input (150) or (150/total), etc. (whatever numbers you need to adjust it). Maybe upload some data that can be applied to the graph, that would at least give us an idea what you are expecting.

Comment: In a typical cumulative distribution curve, the Y-Axis scales from 0 to 1 and represents from 0% to 100% of the population.  In another variation, instead of 0 to 1, the values are shown on the Y-Axis.  I would like to combine them.  I want the values on the left, and I want the 0 to 1 scaling on the right.   Example of the ratio on the left:  https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_cumulative.html

Comment: @MarkGinsburg: [Here's an example of what the code in my answer along with yours produces](https://i.imgur.com/wBXJakW.png), although maybe I'm missing something here perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `ax.twinx()`, as used e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend) and its answers.

Try this approach:

```
ax = plt.gca()  # get current active axis
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(base[:-1], (len(serWEB)-cumulative)/len(serWEB), 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic shell of plotting values on the left Y-Axis and ratio on the right Y-Axis (`ax2`). I used the `twinx()` function as per the comments.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# evaluate the histogram
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick 
values, base = np.histogram(serWEB, bins=100)
#evaluate the cumulative
cumulative = np.cumsum(values)
# plot the cumulative function
plt.plot(base[:-1], cumulative, c='blue')
plt.title('Chart Title')
plt.xlabel('X Label')
plt.ylabel('Y Label')
#plot the survival function
plt.plot(base[:-1], len(serWEB)-cumulative, c='green')
# clone the Y-axis and make a Y-Axis #2
ax = plt.gca() 
ax2  = ax.twinx() 
# on the second Y-Axis, plot the ratio from 0 to 1 
n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(serWEB, 100, normed=True, histtype='step', 
cumulative=True)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,900, step = 14))
plt.xlim(0, 200) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Here is the basic shell of plotting values on the left Y-Axis and ratio on the right Y-Axis (ax2).   I used the twinx() function as per the comments.