# Whats the best way to combine a pandas.datframe.plot() with a matplotlib.pyplot.plot()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I was looking to format the ticks in my y-axis (this thread [Format y axis as percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357611/format-y-axis-as-percent) is great) but a lot of the solutions were causing an AttributeError for my particular code

```
#Example code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# arbitary data to plot
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,2))

#plotting the data and then plotting a 0 line over the top
ax = df.plot()
ax = plt.plot([0,100],[0,0])

vals = ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,.2%}'.format(x) for x in vals])

plt.show()
```

A bit of testing revealed that the second plot call messed up the ax object it went from being: class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot' to class 'list'. Thus it was easy to work-around, don't attribute the second plot to ax:

```
ax = df.plot()
plt.plot([0,100],[0,0])
```

Or move the formatting line up in the code before the ax object gets changed:

```
ax = df.plot()
vals = ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,.2%}'.format(x) for x in vals])
ax = plt.plot([0,100],[0,0])
```

So my question is: What is the best practice? Both the work-around's feel incorrect, what is the best way to assign the plt.plot() call to ax object without changing it? Or would best practice be to use plt.plot(df.index, df) instead of df.plot()?

*Note dp8's answer in [Format y axis as percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357611/format-y-axis-as-percent) "plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:.0f}%'.format(x*100) for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()])" worked regardless of the mess that I made with calls to ax

Comment: why don't you just do ax.plot(....)

Comment: Ahhh, perfect! I knew there was something simple I was missing - Many thanks

Comment: I added it as an answer if you feel like accepting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting mixed up, when you do:

```
ax=df.plot()
```

you've already made the ax object. if you want to add more to it (like another plot) you can simply just use its methods to do this, such as:

```
ax.plot([0,100],[0,0])
```