# Pandas Line Chart - Y Axis converts decimals value as float

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

I have an Pandas Dataframe that is an aggregated output as below:

```
cust_name,measure_1,measure_2
cust_name,10%,20%
```

I am trying to plot a Line chart with this data but I see the y axis is in decimal format (looks like it converts decimal number to float). I am trying to see how can I have the y-axis values to be in percentages and not decimal. For example 10% is plotted along the 0.1 axis and so on.

Comment: use `PercentFormatter()`. It is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319915/10396469

Comment: use `PercentFormatter()`. It is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36319915/10396469