# How to plot an horizontal barplot with percentage distribution from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a large pandas dataframe like this:

In:

```
d = {'type': ['type 1', 'type 2', 'type 2', 'type 3', 'type 1', 'type 4', 'type 5', 'type 6', 'type 6', 'type 7' ], 'value': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes','no', 'yes', 'no']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Out:

```
    type     value
0   type: 1   yes
1   type: 2   no
2   type: 2   yes
3   type: 3   no
4   type: 1   yes
5   type: 4   no
6   type: 5   yes
7   type: 6   no
8   type: 6   yes
9   type: 7   no
```

How can I create an horizontal barplot with the percentage of yes/no values in each bar? So far I tried to:

```
sns.barplot(x='type', y='value', data=df,  orient = 'h')
```

However, I only get the bars with no percentage of the distribution for each yes/no value. How can I draw it in the same bar without splitting it? For example:

[image: example]

In the above example, the total count of yes/no is in the x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.crosstab` to compute the percentage, then `plot.barh` to plot the bars:

```
ax = (pd.crosstab(df['type'], df['value'], normalize='index')
        .plot.barh(stacked=True, alpha=0.8)
     )
```

Output:

[image]

For the numbers on bars, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913104/building-charts-with-value-counts/61913305#61913305).

Comment: Is there any way to put a percentage label in the top of the bar?

Comment: Play with the `x, y` in `ax.text`, e.g `ax.text(x/2, y+barheight...`