# Percentage scaling in my Y axis seaborn lineplot is messy

Tags: seaborn

I was plotting my data using seaborn lineplot but it ends up like this

[image]

Why Y-axis did not display a proper percentage scaling (like 0% to 100%)?

Comment: Looks like your y data are strings

Comment: How to convert the y data to float but keep the % format?

Comment: You'd use the [PercentFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357611/format-y-axis-as-percent)