# Normalizing and Plotting Data of 3 Columns Grouped by 4th Column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, bar-chart

My `dataframe` is as follows, [link](https://pastebin.com/9KRHY04J) to quick .csv. Values `a` and `b` can be considered also as `true` or `false`.

```
+------+------+------+--------+
| COl1 | COl2 | COl3 | Group  |
+------+------+------+--------+
| a    | b    | a    | Yellow |
| b    | b    | a    | Blue   |
| a    | a    | b    | Red    |
| a    | b    | a    | Red    |
| a    | a    | b    | Yellow |
| b    | b    | a    | Blue   |
| b    | b    | a    | Yellow |
| a    | a    | b    | Blue   |
| a    | b    | a    | Red    |
| b    | a    | b    | Blue   |
| b    | b    | a    | Yellow |
| a    | a    | a    | Blue   |
| b    | a    | b    | Red    |
+------+------+------+--------+
```

I want to have a bar plot for the first three columns grouped by the fourth column. Data in the first three columns are categorical, and I would like to have their normalized counts. The number of categories (i.e. the values `a` and `b`) in all the three columns is same. In case of single column, I would generally normalize as:

```
df_grouped = df_main.groupby('Group')['COL1'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100
```

However, when I tried grouping the columns using the code below, I am unable to normalize the counts before plotting it as bar chart it:

```
df_grouped = df_main.groupby('Group')['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'].count().reset_index()
df_grouped.plot.bar()
```

Grouping in the plot like below would be great if possible:
[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also get dummies, groupby and plot if you needed to drill deeper into each COL

```
df1=pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['COl1','COl2','COl3'])
(df1.groupby('Group').mean()*100).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very easy to understand. Is it possible, by anyway to group the bars by the categories `a` and `b`? Basically baking the categories slightly for discriminable etc. to visualization...like col1's a and b bunched together...

Comment: Did you mean`(df.groupby(['COl1','COl2','COl3'])['Group'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100).unstack().plot.bar()`

Comment: I meant something like paired bars position wise, e.g. Col1 'a' and 'b' together and then some space after which col2 'a' and 'b'

Comment: Not sure I understand you. Maybe modify question to include image of what you exactly need done and we can see if doable

Comment: Sure thing. Added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is binary, you can use `groupby` like this:

```
(df.iloc[:,:-1].eq('a')          # `True` class
   .groupby(df['Group']).mean()
   .plot.bar()
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can it somehow be modified to show percentages instead of normal values?

Comment: You can put `.mul(100)` after mean, before plot.

Comment: Or you can use [percentformatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357611/format-y-axis-as-percent)