# How can I fix Problems with Python code in Power BI?

Tags: python, charts, bar-chart, percentage

I want to create bars with this code and I've done it, but my percentages aren't visible correctly. They should be integer values, but they aren't

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import numpy as np

numbers1 = dataset.loc[0:36, 'Today'].tolist()
numbers2 = dataset.loc[0:36, 'Tomorrow'].tolist()
names = dataset.loc[0:36, 'Cities'].tolist()

data = list(zip(names, numbers1, numbers2))
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
sorted_names, sorted_numbers1, sorted_numbers2 = zip(*data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))  # Set the desired graphics dimensions (width, height)

width = 0.4
spacing = 0.1

x = np.arange(len(sorted_names))

rects1 = ax.bar(x - spacing/2, sorted_numbers1, width, color='blue')

for i in range(len(sorted_names)):
    if sorted_numbers1[i] < sorted_numbers2[i]:
        rects1[i].set_color('green')
    elif sorted_numbers1[i] > sorted_numbers2[i]:
        rects1[i].set_color('red')

ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(sorted_names, rotation=45, ha='right')

# Converting the "y" axis to percentages
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.PercentFormatter())

# Adding percentage values above bars
for i, rect in enumerate(rects1):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height, f'{sorted_numbers1[i]}%', ha='center', va='bottom')

# Setting the distances between elements
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4, wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[My bars with non correct percentages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htDKm.png)

[My table with correct percentages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj0Pi.png)

I expect to see normal percentages upon my bars like 74%....66% and next... and side percentages the same...

Comment: Hi @Алейна Дарк your code seems to work fine on dummy data. There is some issue with the data you are using. Please share a sample data to reproduce results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `PercentFormatter(xmax=1.0)`, as suggested in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319915/10176124

If your percentage is formatted as 0-1 you can set xmax to 1, if it is formatted 0-100 you can use the default xmax or use xmax=100. You can also control the number of decimals with the 'decimals' argument, see the documentation for the function here:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter

Comment: Thank you. @P Fernandez my code became much better. But percentages above bars are still 0,27%, 0,25%..... and the same things. But i want to make it like 27%, 25% and next.... maybe you know how to change it?  How can i send you my new code?

Answer (score 0):

It is my new code

````
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import numpy as np

numbers1 = dataset.loc[0:36, 'Відсоток ЗСУ'].tolist()
numbers2 = dataset.loc[0:36, 'PercentTomorrow'].tolist()
names = dataset.loc[0:36, 'Місто'].tolist()

data = list(zip(names, numbers1, numbers2))
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
sorted_names, sorted_numbers1, sorted_numbers2 = zip(*data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

width = 0.4
spacing = 0.1

x = np.arange(len(sorted_names))

rects1 = ax.bar(x - spacing/2, sorted_numbers1, width, color='blue')

for i in range(len(sorted_names)):
    if sorted_numbers1[i] < sorted_numbers2[i]:
        rects1[i].set_color('green')
    elif sorted_numbers1[i] > sorted_numbers2[i]:
        rects1[i].set_color('red')

ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(sorted_names, rotation=45, ha='right')

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=1.0))

for i, rect in enumerate(rects1):
    height = rect.get_height()
    percentage = sorted_numbers1[i] / 100.0  # Convert percentage to decimal
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height, f'{percentage:.2%}', ha='center', va='bottom')  # Format as percentage

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4, wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)

plt.show()```
````