# Seaborn: How to add a "%" symbol after each value in the X axis of a plot, not converting the value to a percentage?

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am just wondering, how do I **add a percentage (%) symbol** after each value in my plot along the X axis, **not converting** the values to a percentage?

For example: Say I have the values 5, 10, 15, 20... How would I make them appear as 5%, 10%, 15%, 20% etc., along the X axis, but not converting them to 0.05%, 0.1%, 0.15%, 0.2% etc.

**Code for my plot:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(
```

- What needs to be added to my plot code to make the percentage (%) symbol appear after each value in my X axis?

```
sns.displot(data=df, x="column_name", kde=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer you question? [Pyplot: using percentage on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26294360/7758804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PercentFormatter()` should work for you as shown in the working example below:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
sns.distplot(x, vertical=True)
```

[image]

Then, at the end do:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
```

[image]

Comment: As the original author of PercentFormatter, I approve :)